# 404 error connecting R to via Sparklyr with livy

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio, sparklyr, livy

I am trying to connect our local machine to Spark with livy method.

We tried with a couple of users, but we get this error:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "link/to/spark/via/livy",
                    version = "2.4",
                    method = "livy",
                      config = 
                        livy_config(
                                    username = 'user',
                                     password = "pwd"))
sc
```

We tried using CURL and the exit status was positive, so I do not get why this is not working, giving 404.

> Error in livy_validate_master(master, config) :
> Failed to connect to Livy service at link/to/spark/via/livy. Failed to
> retrieve livy session (Client error: (404) Not Found):

**Note**: there is the tag RStudio because we used the procedure of RStudio -whom put out the code above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would have sworn that `"link/to/spark/via/livy"` was intended to just be an example placeholder.

Comment: It is an example, I have changed also the error.